# Как пишется "так()же"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, также

Как правильно писать: "также" или "так же"? И в каких случаях что употребляется?

Comment: Спасибо огромное...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если "также" по смыслу можно заменить на союз "и", то есть он выражает что-то, сделанное подобным образом, то пишется слитно.
Пример: "Я также пойду в театр".
Раздельно пишется в тех случаях, когда за "так же" следует союз "как" (фактически или подразумевается по смыслу).
Пример: *"Я умею это делать так же, как и мой друг"*.

Comment: Хорошо, а как быть в предложениях типа. "Также вы можете сделать ..."? Здесь "Также" по смыслу можно заменить на "Кроме того" и оно идёт первым в приложении.

Comment: Только не "и", а "ещё".

Answer (score 11):

**Также** — это сочинительный соединительный союз.
**Так же** — указательное местоимение с частицей.
Для проверки нужно попробовать опустить частицу **же**. Если смысл предложения не нарушается, то пишем раздельно, если нарушается — слитно.
*Он умён, я также. Маша так же, как и Катя, говорит по-французски.*
Это же правило касается правописания слов *чтобы, тоже, зато.*

Answer (score 5):

Правило хорошее, но в отношении именнно этих двух пар (также / так же и тоже / то же) не всегда срабатывает.
Возможны случаи двоякого написания: *Он **очень** умен, я та(?)же*, *Катя говорит по - французски с акцентом, Маша так(?)же*, *Вася ходит в школу через парк, Петя так(?)же.*
Тут оба варианта допустимы.

Поэтому лучше проверять одно другим.
Если возможна замена так(?)же на тоже (и наоборот), то написание слитное.
Если возможна замена так(?)же на "таким же образом, способом" или "тоже так", то раздельное.
То(?)же требует раздельного написания, если допускает замену на "это же", "оно же".
Ну и наконец, если оба условия выполняются (и замена на тоже, и замена на "тоже так" допустимы), то написание зависит от авторского смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно писать: "также" или "так же". И в каких случаях что употребляется?
    Да, действительно, ТАКЖЕ - сочинительный союз, равный по значению союзу ТОЖЕ, обозначает действие, выполненное вслед за кем - то, можно заменить союзом И. Он пошёл в школу, я  ТАКЖЕ (= ТОЖЕ), (= И я пошёл).
  ТАК ЖЕ  - местоимённое наречие, обозначает действие, совершённое по образцу, похожим способом. Можно убрать ЖЕ, можно перед ним добавить ТОЧНО, можно добавить или увидеть союз КАК. Он решил задачу, и я решил её (ТОЧНО) ТАК ЖЕ, КАК и он