# "Также" или "так же"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, также

Правильно ли написание так(?)же в следующих предложениях:

*Здравствуйте, в понедельник я забрала письмо-запрос для передачи его в ... Но я хотела бы узнать, к кому и когда необходимо будет обратиться по поводу места в студенческом общежитии после того, как документы будут привезены. А **также** существует ли необходимость прохождения медосмотра в одной из поликлиник моего родного города?*

Если я совершила ошибку, прошу объяснить с точки зрения правила.

Comment: Подобные вопросы уже задавались: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427967/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be, 
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432165/%d0%92%d1%81%d1%91-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb,  
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/167/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b6%d0%b5, 
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/15307/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b6%d0%b5

Comment: Мой совет (не по теме вопроса). Лучше не выделять последнюю часть в отдельное предложение, не разрывать ваш вопрос (Я хотела бы узнать А, а также Б). В конце такого объединенного предложения не нужен вопросительный знак.

Comment: Приветствие "здравстуйте" стилистически неудачно расположено. Гораздо лучше было бы начать письмо с обращения (Уважаемый Имярек! В понедельник я забрала...)

Answer (score 2):

У вас все верно.

В данном случае **также** союз. Поэтому слитное написание верно.

Союз также можно заменить словами: 
    тоже,
    в равной мере,
    вместе с тем,
    равным образом.
кроме того,  и еще, и

Так же - наречие с частицей же. Употребляются в речи для сравнения каких-либо действий или состояний, протекающих или проявляющихся в сходных условиях или обстоятельствах.

*Я старался подражать отцу во всем: **так же** торопливо пил утренний чай, на ходу одевался и выскакивал из дому, хотя спешить мне в ту пору было некуда.*

*За окном все **так же** моросил холодный дождь, и  казалось, что сероватое осеннее небо опустилось над городом до самых крыш.*

Наречию с частицей «так же» соответствуют следующие синонимы:

```
таким же образом,
точно так же,
как и,
равно как и,
так же как,
подобно,
похоже,
одинаково,
аналогично.
```